# Counting different people associated with one phone number in SAS

Tags: sas, counting

I have a few million records with a list of names and phone numbers. I need to count how many people are associated with each unique phone number. The phone numbers are associated with duplicate names and unique names. So for each phone number I need to count the number of distinct users. Then this needs to be mapped to a list of stores. I tried selecting distinct phones/distinct phones but that only gives me a ratio of a distribution. So for example, if there is 10 people using three phones, then my ratio tells me that 3 phones are distributed among 10 people, but it doesnt tell me the actual number of people withn that distribution associated with the phone. Can anyone please help me with the SAS code to get the correct count where I know exactly how many phones are associated with the same phone number. Thanks in advance.
-r

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the number of distinct rows that have the same phone number, you use:

```
proc sql;
create table phone_number_counts as
 select phonenumber, count(1) as count_users
 from dset
 group by phonenumber;
quit;
```

If you want to find out distinct names within phone number, ie, if
555-123-4567 John H
555-123-4567 John H
555-123-4567 Mary Y

should result in 2, not in 3 (the first code would yield 3), then use `count(distinct name)` instead of `count(1).`

If you want something else, some example data might be helpful - ie, an example of the initial data and an example of a correct final dataset would be helpful.

Comment: Not in the comments, for goodness' sake... post it in the original question as an edit, please.  :)  In the comments would be more appropriate to explain why you don't find the answer useful, if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `count(distinct name)`:

```
proc sql;
  create table phone_number_counts as
  select phonenumber, 
         count(*) as count_rows,
         count(distinct name) as unique_names
  from dset
  group by phonenumber;
quit;
```